# Julia: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Number,1} to an object of type GLM.LmResp

Tags: julia, linear-regression

I am building a DataFrame row by row and then running a regression on it. For simplicity, the code is:

```
using DataFrames
using GLM

df = DataFrame(response = Number[])
for i in 1:10
    df = vcat(df, DataFrame(response = rand()))
end

fit(LinearModel, @formula(response ~ 1), df)
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Number,1} to an object of type GLM.LmResp
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor GLM.LmResp(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Stacktrace:
 [1] fit(::Type{GLM.LinearModel}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Number,1}) at ~/.julia/v0.6/GLM/src/lm.jl:140
 [2] #fit#44(::Dict{Any,Any}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Type{GLM.LinearModel}, ::StatsModels.Formula, ::DataFrames.DataFrame) at ~/.julia/v0.6/StatsModels/src/statsmodel.jl:72
 [3] fit(::Type{GLM.LinearModel}, ::StatsModels.Formula, ::DataFrames.DataFrame) at ~/.julia/v0.6/StatsModels/src/statsmodel.jl:66
 [4] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [5] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
while loading ~/test.jl, in expression starting on line 10
```

The call to the linear regression is very similar to [regression in "Introducing Julia"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/DataFrames#Regression_and_Models):

```
linearmodel = fit(LinearModel, @formula(Y1 ~ X1), anscombe)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours, I realized that GLM requires concrete types and Number is an abstract type (even though the [documentation for GLM.LmResp](https://juliastats.github.io/GLM.jl/latest/index.html#GLM.LmResp) says little about this at the time of this writing, only "Encapsulates the response for a linear model"). The solution is to change the declaration to a concrete type, such as Float64:

```
using DataFrames
using GLM

df = DataFrame(response = Float64[])
for i in 1:10
    df = vcat(df, DataFrame(response = rand()))
end

fit(LinearModel, @formula(response ~ 1), df)
```

Output:

```
StatsModels.DataFrameRegressionModel{GLM.LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,Base.LinAlg.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}

Formula: response ~ +1

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std.Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.408856 0.0969961 4.21518   0.0023
```

The type has to be concrete, e.g. the abstract type `Real` with `df = DataFrame(response = Real[])` fails with a more helpful error message:

```
ERROR: LoadError: `float` not defined on abstractly-typed arrays; please convert to a more specific type
```

Alternatively, you can convert to `Real` after building the dataframe:

```
using DataFrames
using GLM

df = DataFrame(response = Number[])
for i in 1:10
    df = vcat(df, DataFrame(response = rand()))
end

df2 = DataFrame(response = map(Real, df[:response]))

fit(LinearModel, @formula(response ~ 1), df2)
```

This works because converting to Real actually converts to Float64:

```
julia> typeof(df2[:response])
Array{Float64,1}
```

I filed an [issue with GLM](https://github.com/JuliaStats/GLM.jl/issues/239) to improve the error message.